# Check template argument of Base class against values in Derived

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

Lets assume I have an interface class (made-up example, not real code) like

```
template <int year>
class Car {
public: 
  virtual void move(double x, double y) = 0;
  // etc etc
};
```

and a lot of derived classes like

```
template <int year>
class Model8556 : virtual public Car<year> {
private: 
  void move(double x, double y) {
    // ...
  }
  int yearMax = 2000; // different for every model
  int yearMin = 1990;
  // etc etc
};
```

and I choose the model somewhere via

```
Car<foo>* myCar;    
switch (bar) {
  case 1: myCar = new model3434<foo>(); break;
  case 2: myCar = new model8295<foo>(); break;
  // etc
}
```

**I do want to check the template argument of Car (or better: of the derived classes) at compile time**. I want the  template argument year to stay in a certain range (i.e. between yearMin and yearMax). However: this certain range differs between the derived classes. (edit:) **As there are a lot of derived classes, I would prefer a solution within Car.**

How could I achieve this behaviour? Or is this bad design?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `static_assert`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: Are you sure you need to use virtual inheritance?

Comment: @NO_NAME: As opposed to what? Do you suggest "Normal" Inheritance? Is there a rule of thumb for Interfaces?

Comment: @mstrkrft ... the rule is that you don't use virtual inheritance if you don't need to.

Comment: @mstrkrft Virtual inheritance is useful mostly when you use multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I removed it and will do some reading on that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
template <int year>
class Model8556 : virtual public Car<year> {
private: 

  static const int yearMax = 2000; // I assume you meant a static constant
  static const int yearMin = 1990;

  static_assert( yearMin <= year && year <= yearMax,        // Condition
                 "Invalid template argument specified!" );  // Error message
};
```

[**Demo.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/267bf8f29cf7a0bf)
There is no possibility to put this into the base class with the current method; CRTP doesn't work because the derived class would be considered incomplete inside `Car`. However, a change in structure might help.

```
template <int year>
class Car
{
    // Your implementation, as above
};

template <int year,
          int YearMin,
          int YearMax>
class CarChecker : Car<year>
{
    // Optionally declare constants here

    static_assert( YearMin <= year && year <= YearMax,
                   "Invalid template argument specified!" );
};

template <int year>
class Model8556 :
    public CarChecker<year, 1990, 2000> // Specify the minimum and maximum here
{};
```

Comment: I forgot to say: I would prefer this check to be within the base class, as there are a lot of derived classes. Is this possible?

Comment: @mstrkrft Proposed a solution.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work with the above mentioned switch statement, as the Car pointer needs his template arguments. Sorry, I did not test this properly before.

Comment: @mstrkrft Check the second version again, I adjusted it